# After adding IP restriction I get a '403 error' for get_file_contents

Tags: php, ip-restrictions

I have the following code that determines if an image is an SVG or not so that it displays the source if it is (the SVG can then be coloured using CSS):

```
if (strpos('url_to_an_image', '.svg') !== false) {
    echo file_get_contents('url_to_an_image'); 
} else {
    echo '<img src="url_to_an_image" />';
}
```

This worked fine, until I added an IP restriction in htaccess when I get the following error:

> file_get_contents(http://example.com/images/icons/icon-email.svg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

I have tried the solutions that suggest spoofing a real browser request; they don't work.

Is there another solution for this, or another approach I could use to display SVGs?

Comment: where and how are you applying the `ip restriction`?

Comment: in my htaccess file

Comment: Maybe you forgot to allow own IP? Also why use URL when file is located on your system? Use path to file and no IP restrictions will apply.

Comment: Can we see the htaccess file rules used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the 403 error because php doesn't seem to have the permission to open this file. What's your exact code to block the IPs?
Do not use an URL when it's on your own server, just use an absolute path.

Comment: Thank you, it was because I was using the full path!

Comment: You're welcome. It's always the best way to use a path and not a URL since your page will also work on an different domain or server without major changes.

Comment: yeah, I'm using expressionengine cms and it was actually a tag that returned the full url so I didn't realise at first.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue and  finally found out what happened. My VPS provider put in a "deny from all" in the .htaccess after putting in a huge list of "allow from" IP addresses.

They did this because of a bonet attack on the site.